# Generating Function: Why is $G(0)=P(X=0)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, generating-functions

$G$ is the generating function:
$$G(s)=E\left[s^X\right]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(X=i)s^i$$
But the textbook claims that $G(0)=P(X=0)$. Why?
$$G(0)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(X=i)(0)^i=0$$ but this is not $P(X=0)$, this is wrong?

Comment: Almost surely they've established the convention that $0^0 = 1$.

Comment: So I should take it as "by convention" (just like 0!=1)?

Comment: That's the only way to make $G$ (i.e. $x^0$) continuous at $0$ and in some way more than just a "convention" because $x^0$ is more important/ubiquitous than $0^x$ which is not even defined for negative $x$, making the requirement to make it continuous at $0$ less important.

Comment: I think you should look at the definition more closely. Actually it can be expressed as $G(s) = E[s^X] = \Pr\{X = 0\} + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \Pr\{X = i\}s^i$. And as what A.S. said you can take a limiting approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition for $G(s)$ and result of $G(0)$ are both correct.
Since $ 0^0 = 1$, and $0^i = 0$ for $i \in \mathbb(R) \neq 0$, we have 
$$ G(0) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(X=i)(0)^i = P(X=i) \cdot 1 = P(X=i)$$